# File attachement not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, file-upload, attachments

I've created a `Infopath 2010` form with file attachment control as one of its fields. When I publish the form in `SharePoint 2013`, and fill up the form uploading a document in the attachment field, the attached document is not being displayed in the list. The data type of the column in `list settings -> advanced settings` is `single line of text`. So, what could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When I open my email > open the InfoPath attachment > right click on the attached document in my InfoPath form > I have no option to open or save. If I click on the attachment, I receive a "the webpage cannot be displayed" message. Is this a security setting?

Answer (score 1):

Actually InfoPath attachments are stored as pieces of text called base64 encoded strings within the InfoPath form itself.

To be able to store a file as a string, InfoPath converts the binary data of the file to a string.

Once you’ve added a file as an attachment to an InfoPath form, you can use the menu options Open or Save As on the File Attachment control to retrieve the file that was stored in the InfoPath form.

When you select either menu option, InfoPath converts the string it stored previously back to binary data and presents you with the file again.

So AFAIK its not possible to display the attachment as column value in the list.

Comment: Where should I use the menu options? in the Info path form or elsewhere? @Karthik

Comment: @Zane, In the InfoPath File Attachment control.

Comment: would you please elaborate it? I'm a little bit beginner in InfoPath. @Karthik

Comment: If you have worked on file attachment control, on click of an attachment, system will ask for Open or Save as for the attachment, thats what I meant.

Comment: In the list view in sharepoint, it shows up an image button of attachment not the file name of the document that I uploaded. Moreover, once I click on that small button nothing happens. @Karthik

Comment: Attachments are internally encoded and saved inside the form, you need to decode the attachment to open it again, you can decode it either by using c# code or using the file attachment control in Infopath, browser cannot decode the attachment, thats why you dont get to see anything when you click on the image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11495/discussion-between-zane-and-karthik-jaganathan)